# PHP - Get Gateway/Router IP, UPnP

Tags: php, linux, macos, gateway, upnp

I am attempting to create a UPnP method on an internal PHP server if at all possible. I need it to be mostly platform independent so that it may run on Windows, OSX, or Linux.

I believe I can get my SOAP protocols working for UPnP, but first I must determine the IP address of the gateway/router that the server goes through. Is it possible to retrieve this information with PHP? If not, what about Python or Ruby?

I have done this in C# but am looking for a more platform independent method now.

Thanks!

CLARIFICATION: I am looking for the *internal* IP address of the gateway, not the external IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could retrieve it using external services such as whatismyip.com and similar (via cURL).

another option: since most routers allow for telnet connection or have web admin interface, you could login using PHP and just scrape the external IP.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not looking for the external IP address. I want the internal IP address instead.

Comment: ah, that's much easier: router always have permanent (default set) IP address - usually at 192.168.1.1

Comment: also, you could scrape it from the admin interface, if the gateway address could change on the network

Comment: I'm hoping to make this deployable, so gateway IP will be unknown. Not sure but I may be able to use the system() function in PHP and pull it from a "netstat" command? Just an idea.

Comment: yes, but that won't be platform independent probably... but if you can use the `system` command, that would be the easiest way.  `netstat -r` is your option.